# conda-build recipe: install pip package in bld.bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, pip, conda-build

I have a `conda` recipe for a custom package that depends on a `pip` package in a private index.

[Looking at the documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/wheel-files.html#building-a-conda-package-from-a-wheel-file), and [the example it links to](https://github.com/conda/conda-recipes/blob/a796713805ac8eceed191c0cb475b51f4d00718c/python/tensorflow/build.sh#L7), it would seem that it should be possible to install the `pip` package from the `bld.bat` file in my recipe.

I have tried both of the following:

```DOS
xcopy /e "%SRC_DIR%\src" "%SP_DIR%\%PKG_NAME%\"
if errorlevel 1 exit 1
pip install some_package --extra-index-url "https://private_index.com/pip/simple/"
if errorlevel 1 exit 1
```

```DOS
xcopy /e "%SRC_DIR%\src" "%SP_DIR%\%PKG_NAME%\"
if errorlevel 1 exit 1
set PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL="https://private_index.com/pip/simple/"
pip install some_package
if errorlevel 1 exit 1
```

which give me this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement some_package (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for some_package
```

But when I do `pip install some_package --extra-index-url "https://private_index.com/pip/simple/"` in a shell, all works fine.

**What am I doing wrong?**

N.B. There is a valid build for `some_package` for the python version I'm building against.

Comment: your command line command and batch file commands do not match. please clarify.

Comment: @Gerhard I'm not sure what you're referring to. The cmd command, at the end, matches the problematic line in the first example batch file - the rest of the lines are to give context as to what is going on in my `bld.bat` as someone would have surely asked.

Comment: @Gerhard looks like you're my only hope thus far. Any ideas?

Comment: Any update on this? I see the same error when trying to build conda packages using a private pypi index (Gitlab). In my case I'm on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) not Windows. Doing the same but with any other pip-package and without the extra-index-url works.